# @mention in chatterfeed apex

Tags: chatter

Can I tag any user in chatter feed (@mention) from apex?

```
List<Opportunity> testList = [SELECT id,name from opportunity where name LIKE '%test%'];
List<feeditem> testfeed = new List<feedItem>();
for(opportunity opp:testList){
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
    String fullFileURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+ opp.id;
    post.parentId = '0054B000000Tn0Y';
    post.Body = 'This is the action item @[username]'+opp.name;
    post.LinkUrl = fullFileURL ;
    testfeed.add(post);
 }
insert testfeed;
```

Comment: Not with `FeedItem`. You need to use the `ConnectApi` for that. Some light Google research should get you what you need.

Comment: I tried doing that Adrian, but was getting the compilation error: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null,ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me', input, null);           The error is:Method was removed after version 31.0: postFeedItem

Comment: Hmm have you tried compiling a class at a lower version to use it? Not aware of any replacement for it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a structure you can utilize for mentions:

```
    List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

    for(sObject c : [SOQL Query]){

         ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
         ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
         ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
         ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

         messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
         //Mention user here
         mentionSegmentInput.id = c.OwnerId;
         messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

         textSegmentInput.text = '\n'+' Chatter text here';
         messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

         feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
         feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
         feedItemInput.subjectId = c.Id;

         ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);
         batchInputs.add(batchInput);

     }

     ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchinputs);
```

Comment: +1 This code is basically outlined in [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm).

Comment: @sfdcfox How do i get notified when i tag myself?

Comment: @AnuragA I believe you will not be notified on self mention

Answer (score 2):

Also worth looking at this [helper class](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) on GitHub from the Chatter folks

You can then just call a method like this:

```
postFeedItemWithMentions(String communityId, String subjectId, String textWithMentions)
```

and it will post to the record and parse the mentions for you