# Wants to add @mention of the owner name of the case of chatter feed when a new case is created

Tags: chatter-feed, mentions

I have created a trigger and it works without @mention. But I need the owner name of the case on the body of the chatter post.

```
trigger CasePostFeed on Case (after insert) {
    system.debug('POST STARTED');
    
    List <Case> caselistToUpdate = new List<Case>();
    
    for(Case ca: trigger.new) {
        FeedItem FI = new FeedItem();
        system.debug('CASE ID CREATED 1 '+ ca.Id); 
        if(ca.Status == 'New' && ca.RecordTypeId == '0120M000000ATBC') {
            system.debug('CASE ID CREATED 2 '+ ca.Id); 
            FI.CreatedById ='00530000007mCQD';
            FI.ParentId = ca.Id;
            
            FI.Body = 'HI @'+ca.Owner_Name__c
                + '\n'
                + '\n'
                + ca.Subject 
                + '\n'
                + ca.Contact_Name_for_Chatter__c  +' from '+ca.Account_Name_for_Chatter__c +' has submitted a new case.'
                + '\n'
                +'You can find the Case on your Trainee Management dashboard or you can get to it from this post.';
            system.debug('POST CREATED');
            
            insert FI;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118923/mention-in-chatterfeed-apex) might solves your problem

Comment: Hi, Thanks it is working. but still I need to change the running user to a specific user.