# Tag and @mentions in custom LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, chatter-feed, connect-api

I'm attempting to tag a users in a custom lwc component. THis is my current code.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void postFeedItem(String msgTxt, String recordId){        
    ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), recordId, ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, msgTxt);
}
```

This lets me comment but @mention functionality with chatter notification isn't present.

I tried using **ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput** and then inserting this in MessageInput, but didn't get any mention suggestions or proposals like the standard chatter functionality.
Kindly point me to the right direction.

EDIT: My attempt so far:

1. On the lightning-input as text I triggered the apex db call as soon its "@" and >3 chars.
2. I am able to select that user Id.
3. Next move is to post the feed using the chattermention method in connect Api.

   ```
       <lightning-input    "
     data-id="search-input"
       value={searchValue}
       placeholder="Search by user first name or last name"
       onchange={searchKeyword}
       label="Tag User"
       required
   ></lightning-input>


   <template if:true={showRecordList}>
       <ul data-id="waiver-list" class="slds-has-dividers_bottom-space container-border" if:true={userRecord}>
           <template for:each={userRecord} for:item="userList">
               <li key={userList.Id} 
               class="slds-item"
               data-id={userList.Id}
               data-name={userList.Name}
               onclick={selectedId}>{userList.Name}</li>
           </template>
       </ul>
   </template>
   ```

Comment: Check this one: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339605/has-anyone-implemented-custom-mentions-in-lwc

Comment: Thanks @Pavantej I did go through that article already, it uses js lib, I was hoping for a std implementation to leverage.

Comment: @Mnz, did you manage to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use postFeedItemWithMentions instead of postFeedElement. There are numerous examples online on how to achieve this:

- [@mention in chatterfeed apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118923/mention-in-chatterfeed-apex) (view the unaccepted answer posted, includes a github link)
- [Post a Feed Element with a Mention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm) (straight from the docs)